# Calculating direction based on point offsets

Tags: java, math, direction

For my tile-based game, I need to calculate direction based on a given point offset (difference between two points). For example, let's say I'm standing at point (10, 4) and I want to move to point (8, 6). The direction I move at is north-west. What would be the best way to calculate this?

Here's me basic implementation in Java.

```
public int direction(int x, int y) {
    if (x > 0) {
        if (y > 0) {
            return 0; // NE
        } else if (y < 0) {
            return 1; // SE
        } else {
            return 2; // E
        }
    } else if (x < 0) {
        if (y > 0) {
            return 3; // NW
        } else if (y < 0) {
            return 4; // SW
        } else {
            return 5; // W
        }
    } else {
        if (y > 0) {
            return 6; // N
        } else if (y < 0) {
            return 7; // S
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Surely it can be optimised or shortened. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Does that even compile? It doesn't return a value when x and y are both 0.

Comment: It looks fine as it is (modulo the missing `else` found by Matti). You could factor out the "return" statement but that's typically the optimization that might not be one at the bytecode level, and one that the compiler should be able  to do for you anyway. You could factor out the computation of the conditions `y<0` and `y>0` but again, a decent compiler should be able to do this for you. You could change the representation of what a direction is (e.g. a pair of numbers each -1, 0 or 1 for the N/S axis and the W/E axis) to make this method simpler, but it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen Ah you're right (changed). Failed copy-paste...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest to understand way would be making a static array that contains the values for all cases.

```
// Won't say anything about how much these values make sense
static final int[][] directions = {
    {3,  6, 0},
    {5, -1, 2}, // -1 for "no direction", feel free to replace
    {4,  7, 1}
};

public int direction(int x, int y) {
    x = (x < 0) ? 0 : ((x > 0) ? 2 : 1);
    y = (y < 0) ? 0 : ((y > 0) ? 2 : 1);

    return directions[y][x];
}
```

**Edit:** *Now* it's correct (why are so many languages missing a proper `sgn` function?)

Comment: @mohammad shamsi For what input does `Math.sgn` return a value other than -1, 0 or 1?

Comment: @Pascal: I forgot to use `sgn` at first which is probably what prompted his comment. And then I found out that Java doesn't even seem to have `sgn` for integers. Meh.

Comment: Indeed: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4780454 . I hate SO's "feature" of not showing quick edits after posting as edits.

Answer (score 1):

My answers with if conditions :).

```
   public int direction(int x, int y) {
        //0 NE, 1 SE, 2 E, 3 NW, 4 SW, 5 W, 6 N, 7 S, 8 (Same place / Not a direction)  
        int direction = 0;

        if(x < 0){
            direction = 3;
        }else if(x == 0){
            direction = 6;
        }

        if(y < 0){
            direction = direction + 1;
        }else if(y == 0){
            direction = direction + 2;
        }
            return direction;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- define a 2D array to hold all states.
- convert x and y to 0, 1 or 2 based on their value (x>0 or x<0 or x ==0)
- return the specific index of array.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as short and clean as you can get, if you represent the eight cardinal directions this way, as separate enumerated values. You're choosing between eight distinct return values, so a decision tree with eight leaves is the best you can do.

You might get something a little tidier if you split direction into two components (N-S and E-W), but without knowing more about what you *do* with direction, we can't know whether that's worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive and return your direction as a Point or something similar (anyway, an (x,y) tuple). So if you're standing in p0 = (10, 4) and want to move to p1 = (8, 6), the result would be (in pseudocode):

```
norm(p1 - p0) = norm((-2,2)) = (-1,1)
```

You can calculate the norm of an integer if you divide it by its absolute value. So for a point you calculate the norm of both members. Just bear in mind that (-1,1) is more expressive than 3 and you can operate in an easier fashion with it.

If you need specific operations, you can create your own Java Point class or extend the existing ones in the library.